# using a values returned from a function in another query inside a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying the construct a Postgres function which can use the result of another select in where clause. The following works fine

```
create or replace function get_film_count(a varchar[], v varchar[])
 RETURNS Table(costs decimal, id varchar, in_node varchar[], out_node varchar[], cycle BOOLEAN,visted_list varchar[])
 language plpgsql
 as
 '
 begin
   RETURN QUERY  SELECT  edg.costs, edg.id, ARRAY[edg.in_node], ARRAY[edg.out_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]
        FROM edges edg where edg.in_node=ANY(a) AND edg.in_node != ANY(v)
        union all 
            SELECT  edg.costs, edg.id, ARRAY[edg.in_node], ARRAY[edg.out_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]
        FROM edges edg where edg.in_node=ANY(SELECT edg.out_node
        FROM edges edg where edg.in_node=ANY(a) AND edg.in_node != ANY(v));
 end;
';
select * from get_film_count(ARRAY['a'], ARRAY['']);
```

However I am looking for something similar to the following

```
create or replace function get_film_count(a varchar[], v varchar[])
 RETURNS Table(costs decimal, id varchar, in_node varchar[], out_node varchar[], cycle BOOLEAN,visted_list varchar[])
 language plpgsql
 as
 '
 begin
   list_of_out_nodes= select out_node from (get_film_count(ARRAY(edg.out_node), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]))
   RETURN QUERY  SELECT  edg.costs, edg.id, ARRAY[edg.in_node], ARRAY[edg.out_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]
        FROM edges edg where edg.in_node=ANY(a) AND edg.in_node != ANY(v)
        union all 
            SELECT  edg.costs, edg.id, ARRAY[edg.in_node], ARRAY[edg.out_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]
        FROM edges edg where edg.in_node=ANY(list_of_out_nodes);
 end;
';
select * from get_film_count(ARRAY['a'], ARRAY['']);
```

So basically I am looking for using calling the function recursively instead and get the value of a column as list and feed it in the RETURN QUERY
Note: I am aware of recursive functionality of Postgres but I am specifically looking for this approach

Comment: Don't have an answer, but your life will be a lot easier if you use dollar quoting for the function body per [Structure pl/psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html): *The function body is simply a string literal so far as CREATE FUNCTION is concerned. It is often helpful to use dollar quoting (see Section 4.1.2.4) to write the function body, rather than the normal single quote syntax. Without dollar quoting, any single quotes or backslashes in the function body must be escaped by doubling them. ...*

Comment: Thanks and I tried with $$ but I was getting an error so I read somewhere suggesting to ' instead. If you have suggestion regarding to how to use $$ please share :). Using this version of postgres: https://scriptable.com/how-to-install-postgresql-mac-docker/

Comment: Read the link I posted in my comment.

Comment: There are too many errors obfuscating the exact objective of the recursive function. Here are some examples of working recursive functions in  PL/pgSQL: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294168/3684, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/302567/3684. Also, why the [outdated Postgres version 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)?

Comment: This is the postgres I have PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit I do not think it is 9.5 though
Thanks for the link actually even with Paul answer below I do get from clause error but I think that is valid query

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to need a CTE to allow the set returned by the first function call to be usable in the second call, something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_film_count(a varchar[], v varchar[])
RETURNS TABLE(costs decimal, id varchar, in_node varchar[], out_node varchar[], cycle BOOLEAN, visited_list varchar[])
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    list_of_out_nodes varchar[];
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY  
        WITH recursive_nodes AS (
            SELECT edg.out_node 
            FROM get_film_count(ARRAY[edg.out_node], v || ARRAY[edg.in_node])
        )
        SELECT edg.costs, edg.id, ARRAY[edg.in_node], ARRAY[edg.out_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]
        FROM edges edg 
        WHERE edg.in_node = ANY(a) AND edg.in_node != ANY(v)
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT edg.costs, edg.id, ARRAY[edg.in_node], ARRAY[edg.out_node], edg.in_node = ANY(v), v || ARRAY[edg.in_node]
        FROM edges edg 
        WHERE edg.in_node = ANY((SELECT * FROM recursive_nodes));
END; $$;
```

---

*Can't say I'm over-the-moon keen on the concept however. Seems unduly "smart" and may be a support problem (this is just gut feel!).*

Comment: Thanks a lot let me play with it and see if it work. I will update the result here

Comment: I get [Code: 0, SQL State: 42P01]  ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "edg"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function get_film_count(character varying[],character varying[]) line 5 at RETURN QUERY
when I call it this way: select * from get_film_count(ARRAY['a'], ARRAY['']); not sure which from it is talking about

Comment: Try running the query portion only. Debug that, then rework as function. I do not have your tables or data so I cannot debug for you.

Comment: Actually the problem is this         WITH recursive_nodes(out_node) AS (
            SELECT edg.out_node FROM get_film_count(ARRAY[edg.out_node], v || ARRAY[edg.in_node])
        ) when I remove it it starts working again I can provide the queries for creating nodes and edhges and insert data actually if that helps
but seems that the function call part not working and returns that error

Comment: Then I don't think I can help further. I don't think you can recursively call the function directly and believed that a CTE could overcome that - but perhaps not.

Comment: No worries and thanks a lot for the help so far. at least it gives me a good idea. appreciate it